# How can I stop Opus audio files skipping when played from the SD card?

Tags: external-sd, music, 7.1-nougat

I'm on LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2). When I play music off of my SD card using the built-in music player, it does fine with MP3 and AAC.

The real problem is when I play opus files. They are recognized by Android since I made their extension `.ogg`, but when I play them, they have random pauses and stutters during playback.

I've tested with the `.ogg` files in internal memory, and there are no skipping problems. On the other hand, there are no skipping problems with anything other than opus files on the external SD card.

Answer (score 0):

I would exclude SD-related problems because other formats are played normally.

Have you tried to open them with a third-party android app like [VLC media player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc&hl=en)? (*It also natively supports .opus files*)

By the way, I suggest you to rename them as **.opus.ogg** or use an Opus To Mp3 converter app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=grant.opus.to.mp3&hl=en) to avoid any further problem.

> Android version 6.0 ("Marshmallow") is able to playback Opus audio >encapsulated in Ogg containers, but the filename extension .opus is not >recognized by built-in players.[48] As a workaround, simply renaming the files >to the double filename extension .opus.ogg allows them to be treated like other >supported audio formats and indexed by the media scanner service.
>   (*from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format))*)

Comment: Tried with VLC as you suggested, and opus files play fine from the external SD (no stuttering/skipping). It seems to me that the only time there's any trouble is when the opus files are on the SD card, so I don't see why I should exclude SD-related problems.

Comment: So the problem shows up only when using the built-in media player but works fine whit VLC? Changing the files extension **.opus** into **.opus.ogg**  doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes. The problem with stuttering/skipping audio playback for opus files only appears with the built-in media player. I've already changed the extension of all my opus files to .opus.ogg prior to all of this.